# named[773]: error (host unreachable) resolving 'B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET/AAAA/IN': 128.63.2.53#53

Tags: linux, networking, dns, bind, debian-jessie

I keep getting the following error messages in my syslog:

```
named[773]: error (host unreachable) resolving 'B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET/AAAA/IN': 128.63.2.53#53
```

It seems to happen for all the root servers too.

I'm running bind 9 on Debian. I'm able to download updates from the server so I know the connection to the Internet is good. I'm also able to reach my server from the Internet without issues and query my zone records.

Any ideas what's going on? This only happens so far on my second name server. Both are set as masters and I'm not using slaves. I have recursion set to no.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my third NS server IP didn't register with my domain registrar. Now that it has, I haven't seen the errors occur again. I'll keep an eye on the logs to confirm.

Edit: spoke too soon. My NS3 server is now shooting these root errors.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the above information to it, instead of posting it as an answer.